# Problems using protobufs with java and scala

Tags: java, scala, protocol-buffers

I have a file `xxx.proto`. I downloaded the protobuf compiler and installed it. Then I issued this command

```
protoc --java_out=./ xxx.proto
```

and it generated my xxx.java

Now I want to compile this file into a class file which I can use with Scala.

```
javac xxx.java
```

Which gives me this error

```
xxx.java:7: package com.google.protobuf does not exist
      com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry registry) {
                         ^
xxx.java:12450: package com.google.protobuf.Descriptors does not exist
  private static com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.Descriptor
                                                ^
xxx.java:12453: package com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage does not exist
    com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.FieldAccessorTable

...
...
...

100 errors
```

Now I guessed, it doesnt have the package.

So I copied the class files of package com.google.protobuf into the same folder where xxx.java exists. Note - I didnt compile this package. I downloaded the jar from another extension which had the jar files. So I extracted them. Now my current path where xxx.java resides has com/google/protobuf/ *.class of protobuf library.

I issued the javac command again.

This time I got a different set of errors -

```
    xxx.java:10: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : class MessageOrBuilder
    location: package com.google.protobuf
          extends com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder {
                                     ^
    xxx.java:215: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : class MessageOrBuilder
    location: package com.google.protobuf
            extends com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder {
                                       ^
    xxx.java:608: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : class MessageOrBuilder
    location: package com.google.protobuf
            extends com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder {
                                       ^
    xxx.java:1017: cannot find symbol
    symbol  : class MessageOrBuilder
    location: package com.google.protobuf
            extends com.google.protobuf.MessageOrBuilder {

..... 100 errors
```

I even tried to compile the source files which came with google protobufs. The generated java classes are giving the same errors.

Any ideas what to do ??

**Answer**

Okay. Thanks everyone.

The main problem is that protocol buffers compiler package from google doesnt by default create the java library. I assumed that it does and installs it. It actually does if you are  running Maven. But i didnt have maven

So i compiled the code in `/java/src` and used the jar. 
                                       ^

Comment: Right, you need to compile java subdirectory in protobuf on your own (typically using Maven, since there is pom.xml file), and use resulting jar file when compiling your generated java sources. Or you can just download jar file, for example from Maven repository (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java, click Binary).

Answer (score 7):

When compiling, you need to have protobuf lib on your classpath. All those missing packages and classes are from protobuf lib.

Find protobuf jar and use

```
javac -cp path/to/protobuf.jar xxx.java
```

Comment: Yup just did that. I put the protobuf jar at the same directory and it shows the second set of errors above "cannot find symbol" ..... the first ones are gone.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use version 2.4.1 (or 2.4+, at least) of the protobuf kit, *including* making sure that you update protoc (the protobuf compiler) *and* recompile your proto definition using the new protoc.  (In other words, everything has to be the same version:

- the protobuf-vn.n.n.jar file;
- the protoc compiler; and
- the *output* of compiling your .proto files with protoc.

One I got everything synched, I began to move forward with a Clojure project I'm looking at.  You may be encountering the same version skew problem.

Answer (score 0):

> protoc -I=$SRC_DIR --java_out=$DST_DIR $SRC_DIR/addressbook.proto

you can download protoc.exe (new release) from>>.

> https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/detail?name=protoc-2.5.0-win32.zip&can=2&q=

in your  *.proto file you correctly config

```
option java_package = "com.example.package";
option java_outer_classname = "class name";
```

Answer (score -1):

One can install the protobuf jar file using the ubuntu a

```
apt-get install libprotobuf-java
```

This will copy the protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar under /usr/share/java/

Hope this helps

Comment: Official distro to download the version, https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/downloads