# Java : com.google.protobuf does not exist

Tags: java, linux, google-app-engine, protocol-buffers, google-wave

I try to install [Walkaround](http://code.google.com/p/walkaround/), a project based on Google Wave. I followed [the official wiki](http://code.google.com/p/walkaround/wiki/RunningTheCode) for installation.

But during the last step (./runant run), I've 100 errors:

```
Proto.java:7: package com.google.protobuf does not exist
      com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistry registry) {
                         ^
Proto.java:12450: package com.google.protobuf.Descriptors does not exist
  private static com.google.protobuf.Descriptors.Descriptor
                                                ^
Proto.java:12453: package com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage does not exist
    com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.FieldAccessorTable

...
...
100 errors
```

**Similar topic:** [Problems using protobufs with java and scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265801/problems-using-protobufs-with-java-and-scala). So I try this solution after searching a proto.jar and the Proto.java:

```
javac -cp 
    ~/walkaround/third_party_src/wave/trunk/dist/proto.jar
    ~/walkaround/proto_src/com/google/walkaround/proto/Proto.java
```

**But I get the same 100 errors.**

Someone can help me? I have no knowledge about Ubuntu Linux and Java environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem.
The reason on my Project was that ./get-third-party-deps failed.
That was fixed by installing build-essential on my ubuntu machine

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
./get-third-party-deps
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm on vacation, I test next week.

Answer (score 0):

You may jar xf proto.jar to see if those classes are in the jar.

If there is anything wrong, you may get it from http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/checkout

It contains c and java source code, you need java parts.

Comment: I have no errors with `jar xf path/proto.jar`. Where do I put the java classes from http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/source/checkout? Thanks for helping.

Comment: That command just expand the jar, you may check if the classes are packed inside.

Comment: For simple, you may just copy the whole java source code into your project. Or you may build and jar from it to replace current proto.jar .